# Taxi Calculator Google Maps

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to be able to use Google Maps to calculate miles from what a user inputed using Dropdown addresses earlier in the form. The map/calculations need to be at bottom.  Where can I find help on this.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Agreed; this would be better off as a comment, though, and the question closed